# ios 7.0.3 jquery mobile multi select issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

Can anyone else running iOS 7.0.3 
Help me confirm an issue with multiple select boxes in phonegap application? 
When I select the jquery mobile select menu with "multiple:multiple" attribute, app crashes.
Works fine when I remove "multiple:multiple" attribute.

It looks like its works on other OS version except 7.0.3.
I am testing the app on iPhone 5 with OS version of 7.0.3

Comment: do you add `data-native-menu="false"` to select?

Comment: No, I am using data-native-menu="true"

Comment: Add it if you want to to use JQM styles. If you don't want to use JQM styles, add `data-role="none"`.

Comment: but whatever it is , if I add "multiple = multiple" property to the select menu, it crashes . Can someone please help .

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any luck?